# Initializing array of pointers to char from a 2d char array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a function

```
int executeCommand(char args[][TOKENSIZE]){
  char *argv[] = {args[0], args[1]}; // This works
  char *argv[] = {args}; // This doesn't
}
```

The args variable will not be of fixed length so I can't use the first line as it is. I don't want to use malloc or free due to some reasons. Is there any way of initializing this argv array from args without hard coding the number of entries.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Just pass the length of the `args` variable to the function so you know how many there are.

Comment: Even if there are  how can I initialize it.

Comment: Why do you need to initialize it; it is a pointer. There's no need to copy the entire pointer array.

Comment: @chux args is not an array of pointers.

Comment: @MateoConLechuga the input is not a pointer array.

Comment: It is not really possible to use an array without knowing its size somehow. How are you planning to use argv?

Comment: @n.m. True about "args is not an array of pointers".

Answer (score 2):

The function needs to know the size somehow or it is mission impossible. One possible way is to use pointers to VLA:

```
int executeCommand(size_t n, char args[n][TOKENSIZE]){
  char* argv[n];
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    argv[i] = args[i];
  }
}
```

As for you why you can't simply use `args` instead of copying the array addresses, I have no idea.

A complete hard-copy of the data would look like

```
char argv[n][TOKENSIZE];
memcpy(argv, args, sizeof(char[n][TOKENSIZE]));
```

Comment: If `argv[]` is used like the `argv[]` of `main()`, then `argv[n]` should be `NULL`, so `char* argv[n+1]; ... argv[n] = NULL;`.  BTW: Could use `memcpy(argv, args, sizeof argv);` Yet OP's goal is a bit unclear.  Nice answer to old question.